# combining 2 month and year columns with different criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm in a bit of a pickle here.

I am working with a table with the columns `month` and `year`.

I need to return (for example) all the columns where:

- `month` is 3 or higher AND `year` is 2014
- AND
- `month` is 2 or lower AND `year` is 2015

So basically everything from 3-2014 to 2-2015

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE student_id = 5
AND ((month >= 3 AND year >= 2014)
AND (month <= 2 AND year <= 2015))
```

`student_id` is not unique

Tried with `AND` at the end and with `OR`
`OR` returns everything, `AND` returns nothing which makes perfect sense since it's returning exactly what I've asked for. I'm also not sure how `JOIN` will  help first criteria returns everything after those numbers and first one returns everything before those dates.

One option is to create a new column with a timestamp of the month and year and use that.

But is there a way to achieve this with current structure with just mysql?

Comment: what's the id in your query? should it be there? if you remove the id and replace the AND between (month >= 3 AND year >= 2014) and (month <= 2 AND year <= 2015) with OR it should do what you want. Also you probably want to have year = 2014 right?

Comment: @user3012759 that's another column in the table where id refers to the student id. There are many rows.  I've renamed the columns in the example so it's easy to follow

Comment: question updated to explain id - changed to `student_id` and it's not unique

Comment: Genius.. that worked.. plz post as answer (=2014) did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you really mean to have records where:

```
 month is 3 or higher AND year is 2014
```

AND records where:

```
 month is 2 or lower AND year is 2015
```

then you want to have

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
  student_id = $id
  AND ((month >= 3 AND year = 2014)
       OR (month <= 2 AND year = 2015))
```

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer lol.. so i'll just wait here and stare at screen or set an alarm for this highly classified task.. SO should rethink some rules. Other than that, thanks a lot - worked perfectly